# Sliding Window over image results in 'out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type'

Tags: octave

When I run `mode` over an image I am getting an error:

> error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type
>   error: called from
>       im2col at line 134 column 13
>       nlfilter at line 79 column 8
>       colour_blocks at line 11 column 7

What is exactly the problem here and what can I do to overcome this? Is it that I am inefficiently iterating over the image? The object is to create a sliding window (256x256) over the image and compute the most frequent colour in each window.

```
pkg load image;
pkg load signal;

% the image is quite small 400x400px
i = uint32(imread('foo.jpg'));


% encode 3 channel image into single channel
ienc = 1+bitor(bitor(i(:,:,1), bitshift(i(:,:,2),8)), bitshift(i(:,:,3),16));

% find the mode
imode = nlfilter(ienc, [256 256], @(x) mode(x(x~=0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that your sliding window is too large. Take a look at the [`nlfilter` source code](http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/image/file/617861a926ec/inst/nlfilter.m).

256*256 window means each window has `65536` elements. If your image is 1024*1024, you will have 6.8719e+10 views but your Octave, built with 32 bit indexing, can't handle arrays with more than 2147483647 elements. Also, if your image is of class double, the views will take around 550GB memory.